# What does this LDAP error mean? "00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090B0B, comment: Error processing control, data 0, v3839"

Tags: c, active-directory, ldap

This against an active directory LDAP server.  The code is running on RHEL6.

Code:

```
static void waitforuser ( const char * netid ) {
        LDAP *          ld              = NULL;
        char            ldapuri[]       = "ldaps://windc1.iastate.edu";
        char            binddn[]        = BINDDN;
        int             msgid           = 0;
        struct berval   passwd          = { 0, NULL };
        int             protocol        = LDAP_VERSION3;
        LDAPMessage *   result          = NULL;
        LDAPMessage *   msg             = NULL;
        int             err             = 0;
        char **         refs            = NULL;
        char            base[]          = "dc=iastate,dc=edu";
        int             scope           = LDAP_SCOPE_SUBORDINATE;
        char *          filter          = NULL;
        char **         attrs           = NULL;
        int             attrsonly       = 0;
        LDAPControl **  sctrls          = NULL;
        LDAPControl **  cctrls          = NULL;
        LDAPControl **  ctrls           = NULL;
        char *          matcheddn       = NULL;
        char *          text            = NULL;
        struct timeval  tv_timelimit    = { 2, 0 };
        int             sizelimit       = 0;            /* no limit */
        int             rc              = 0;

        rc = ldap_initialize(&ld, ldapuri);
        if (rc != LDAP_SUCCESS) {
                fprintf(stderr,
                    "Could not create LDAP session handle for URI=%s (%d): %s\n",
                    ldapuri, rc, ldap_err2string(rc));
                return;
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "about to ldap_set_option(PROTOCOL_VERSION)\n");
        rc = ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &protocol);
        if (rc != LDAP_SUCCESS) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not set LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION %d\n", protocol);
                return;
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "about to ldap_simple_bind_s\n");
        rc = ldap_simple_bind_s(ld, binddn, SHHHH);
        fprintf(stderr, "ldap_simple_bind_s => %d (%s)\n", rc, ldap_err2string(rc));

       asprintf(&filter, "sAMAccountName=%s", netid);
        attrs = calloc(2, sizeof(char *));
        attrs[0] = strdup("sAMAccountName");
        attrs[1] = NULL;
        rc = ldap_search_ext(ld, base, scope, filter, attrs, attrsonly,
                sctrls, cctrls, &tv_timelimit, sizelimit, &msgid);
        if (rc != LDAP_SUCCESS) {
                fprintf(stderr, "ldap_search_ext: %d (%s)\n", rc, ldap_err2string(rc));
                return;
        }
        while ((rc = ldap_result(ld, msgid, LDAP_MSG_ONE, &tv_timelimit, &result)) > 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "There are %d messages\n", ldap_count_messages(ld, result));
                for (msg = ldap_first_message(ld, result);
                     msg != NULL;
                     msg = ldap_next_message(ld, msg)) {
                        fprintf(stderr, " ldap_msgtype(%p) = %d\n", msg, ldap_msgtype(msg));
                        if (ldap_msgtype(msg) == LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT) {
                                fprintf(stderr, "  LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT\n");
                                rc = ldap_parse_result(ld, msg, &err, &matcheddn, &text, &refs, &ctrls, 0);
                                               fprintf(stderr, "ldap_parse_result:       err: %d\n", err);
                                if (matcheddn) fprintf(stderr, "ldap_parse_result: matcheddn: '%s'\n", matcheddn);
                                               fprintf(stderr, "ldap_parse_result:      refs: %p\n", refs);
                                               fprintf(stderr, "ldap_parse_result:     ctrls: %p\n", ctrls);
                                if (rc != LDAP_SUCCESS) {
                                        fprintf(stderr, "ldap_parse_result: ERR %d (%s)\n", rc, ldap_err2string(rc));
                                } else {
                                        fprintf(stderr, "ldap_parse_result:      text: '%s'\n", text ? text : "NULL!");
                                }
                        }
                        ldap_msgfree(result);
                }
        }
}
```

Results:

```
ldap_simple_bind_s => 0 (Success)
There are 1 messages
 ldap_msgtype(0x1e738a0) = 101
  LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT
ldap_parse_result:       err: 80
ldap_parse_result:      refs: (nil)
ldap_parse_result:     ctrls: (nil)
ldap_parse_result:      text: '00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090B0B, comment: Error processing control, data 0, v3839'
```

A similar query using the ldapsearch tool works fine:

```
#!/bin/sh
netid="john"
user=xxxxxx@iastate.edu
passwdfile=/home/john/secret
base="dc=iastate,dc=edu"
connect="-s sub -W -D $user -y $passwdfile -b $base -LLL -l 2 -o nettimeout=2"
url=ldaps://windc1.iastate.edu
ldapsearch -H $url $connect sAMAccountName=$netid sAMAccountName
```

Results:

```
dn: CN=john,OU=Users,OU=ITS,DC=iastate,DC=edu
sAMAccountName: john
```

Comment: Your function is too large to be readable.

Comment: It's likely that your LDAP server doesn't support the "subordinates" search scope (which I've never seen supported out of the box with OpenLDAP or Active Directory). The equivalent of ldapsearch' `-s sub` is `LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE`. @wildplasser what about the scrollbar, is it too large to be usable?

Comment: `if (rc != LDAP_SUCCESS) {` <<-- maybe you need to check `err` (too), instead of `rc` ?

Comment: `err` is printed out and is '80' (whatever that means).  And the ldapsearch command that works includes `-s sub`.

Comment: Yes, I meant you need to set the scope to `LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE` instead of `LDAP_SCOPE_SUBORDINATE` to get the same result.

Comment: @EricLavault Yes, thank you.  Please write this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your LDAP server doesn't support the "subordinates" search scope (which I've never seen supported out of the box with OpenLDAP or Active Directory).

To get the same result as ldapsearch' `-s sub` you need to set the scope to `LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE` instead of `LDAP_SCOPE_SUBORDINATE`.